# Blazor - Component "intellisense" for parameter value

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor component with a parameter `Position`. This parameter should only accept `Top` or `Bottom` for values.

Is it possible set up "intellisense" for this, so when value for `Position` should be entered a pop-up with only these to settings goes out?

---

**Position.cs**

```
public enum Position
{
    Top,
    Bottom
}
```

**MyComponent.razor**

```
@inherits MyComponentBase

<div class="@PositionClass"></div>
```

**MyComponent.razor.cs**

```
public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public Position Position { get; set; } = ToastPosition.TopRight;

    protected string PositionClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
]
```

**Index.razor**

```
<MyComponent Position="Position.Bottom" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
//    here \/
Position="Position.Bottom"
```

For the intellisense, you are passing a string because you haven't used the `@` symbol.

When typing, you should do `Position="(CURSOR IS HERE)"` and then type `@` so it will get the correct intellisense.

Comment: Thanks Vencovsky, the VS intellisense is working that way. But I would like to ask the question differently. Currently I need to add a using statement to the Enum ```Position``` in order to be able to use it. Is it achievable to set up something like a "custom intellisense", so when I type ```... Position="``` and this custom pop up shows with only two available oprions ```Top & Bottom```?

Comment: To create a "custom intellisense" you would need to [create a vs extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-statement-completion?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN). But try adding the `@using Foo.Bar.PlaceOfEnum` and then type `Position="` to see if the intellisense works the way you want.

Comment: @imb13 I teste it here, looks like the intellisense isn't that good yet, it's also slow, but what you can do is type `Position="@` and then press `Ctrl + Space` (windows) to get the enum, then press `.` to see the options. But to do all that, you need to already have the using for the enum.

Comment: Thank you @Vencovsky. Appreciate your help. I guess I will stick with what it is as for now.